# ajax - not sending data which contains a hyphen

Tags: ajax

I have my code as such

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#submit").submit(function() {
    // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
    var word = $('#word').attr('value');
    var sentence = $('#sentence').attr('value');
    var email = $('#email').attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/sentence-examples/suggestsentence.php?",
            data: "sentence="+ sentence+
            "&word="+ word+
            "&email="+ email,
            success: function(data){
                $('form#submit :input').not('input[type="submit"]').val("");
                $('div.success').fadeIn();
                $('div.success').html(data);
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
});
function hide(obj) {
    var el = document.getElementById(obj);
    el.style.display = 'none';
}
```

For what ever reason which I cannot figure out when "word" contains a hyphen like "half-breed" it will not pass the variable to my script. It comes up blank.

Any help?

Comment: Try with `data: {sentence: sentence}` (just a guess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- do not use `.attr('value')` but `.val()` instead. (*`var word = $('#word').val();`*)
- do not manually construct the parameter string, but use

  ```
  data: {
     sentence: sentence,
     word: word,
     email: email
  }
  ```
- no need for the `?` at the end of the url since you are using the `data:` option
- check if the problem is in the ***/sentence-examples/suggestsentence.php*** file and in how it processes the submitted data